# ASP XML select node by specific node value?

Tags: xml, asp-classic

```
<fruits>
  <fruit>apple</fruit>
  <fruit>pear</fruit>
  <fruit>grape</fruit>
</fruits>
```

I want to select  node by using node's value "apple"
and remove node

when I googled it, there are only ways to get node's value

Comment: Did you try simply running `replace(xmlVariable, "<fruit>apple</fruit>","")`? If you want to delete this after it has been loaded, you'll need to use something like Javascript, but if it's deleted at runtime the replace-method should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting fruit nodes (using XPath) where the inner text contains 'apple'.  Once obtained, enumerate through the results informing the parent node (fruits) to remove the selected child node(s) that were returned by the XPath selection.

For example, here's a simplified example that assumes the XML file is loaded locally (via file I/O), and whose results are saved to a new file (for review):

```
With Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    .async = False 
    .load("data.xml")
    Dim apple, apples : Set apples = .documentElement.selectNodes("/fruits/fruit[text()='apple']")
    For Each apple In apples
        apple.parentNode.removeChild(apple)
    Next
    .save("data2.xml")
End With
```

Hope this is helpful.